# Using Matlab's Solve() with Symbolic Constants

Tags: matlab

I'm have a system of two questions with two unknown variables that I'm trying to use Matlab's solve() function to solve, but hitting errors that are almost surely on my end. I'm trying to solve [The following two equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGj4H.png) where r, lambda, and X are constants. To do so, I've been trying to run the following:

```
clear all;
syms VA VB r X L;
assumeAlso(VB <= VA);
assumeAlso(0 <=  VB);
assumeAlso(0 < r <= 1);
assumeAlso(0 < L);
assumeAlso(0 < X);
assumeAlso(VA, 'real');
assumeAlso(VB, 'real');
assumeAlso(r, 'real');
assumeAlso(L, 'real');
assumeAlso(X, 'real');


eqns = [VA == ((r*VA + L*(VA-VB))^2)/(2*X*(r+2*L)) + (L*(VA+VB)*(r*VA+L*(VA-VB)))/(X*(r+2*L)) + ...
(((r^2/L+r)*VA + r*VB)^2 - (r*VA+L*(VA-VB))^2)/(2*X*(r+L)) + ...
(L*VB*((r+L)*VB - L*VA + r^2/L*VA))/(X*(r+L)) + ...
(X/(2*r)) - (((r^2/L+r)*VA+r*VB)^2)/(2*X*r) - VA*(1-1/X*((r^2/L+r)*VA+r*VB)), ...
...
VB == (L^2*VA^2 - L^2*VB^2 + r*VA*(L*VA+L*VB))/(X*(r+2*L)) + ...
(L*VA*(r^2/L*VA + r*VB - L*(VA-VB)))/(X*(r+L)) + ...
(VA*(X-((r^2/L+r)*VA + r*VB)))/X];

S = solve(eqns,[VA VB])
```

My goal is to solve for VA and VB in terms of r, X, and L, which seems like it should be possible. When I fill in values for r, L and X I am easily able to obtain a solution.

When I run this code, however, I get the message:

```
 Warning: Explicit solution could not be found.
```

which normally I would interpret to mean that there is in fact no solution, but when I run

```
S = solve(eqns)
```

I do not get the same output, but:

```
(solvelib::cartesianPower(R_, 2) minus solvelib::VectorImageSet(matrix([[z], [0]]), z, C_)) intersect solvelib::VectorImageSet(matrix([[-(VA^4*x^5 - 2*L^5*VA*VB^3 - 2*L^5*VA^3*VB - L*VA^4*x^4 - 3*L^4*VA^4*x + L^4*VB^4*x + 4*L^5*VA^2*VB^2 - 5*L^2*VA^4*x^3 + 4*L^3*VA^4*x^2 + L^3*VB^4*x^2 + 4*L^2*VA^2*VB^2*x^3 - 5*L^3*VA^2*VB^2*x^2 + 4*L*VA^3*VB*x^4 + L^4*VA*VB^3*x + 9*L^4*VA^3*VB*x + L*VA^2*VB^2*x^4 + 2*L^2*VA*VB^3*x^3 + 2*L^3*VA*VB^3*x^2 - 8*L^3*VA^3*VB*x^2 - 8*L^4*VA^2*VB^2*x)/(L^4*VA^3 - L^4*VB^3 - L^4*VA*VB^2 + L^4*VA^2*VB)], [x]]), x, R_ intersect RootOf(z^6 + (z^5*(L*VA^4 + L*VA^2*VB^2 + 4*L*VA^3*VB))/VA^4 + (z^4*(- 7*L^2*VA^4 + 2*L^2*VA*VB^3 + 8*L^2*VA^3*VB + 6*L^2*VA^2*VB^2))/VA^4 + (z^3*(- 5*L^3*VA^4 + L^3*VB^4 + 6*L^3*VA*VB^3 - 6*L^3*VA^3*VB + 4*L^3*VA^2*VB^2))/VA^4 + (z^2*(7*L^4*VA^4 + 3*L^4*VB^4 + 6*L^4*VA*VB^3 - 2*L^4*VA^3*VB - 14*L^4*VA^2*VB^2))/VA^4 - (z*(6*L^5*VA^4 - 2*L^5*VB^4 - 16*L^5*VA^3*VB + 12*L^5*VA^2*VB^2))/VA^4 + (L^6*VA^4 + L^6*VB^4 - 4*L^6*VA*VB^3 - 4*L^6*VA^3*VB + 6*L^6*VA^2*VB^2)/VA^4, z)) intersect solvelib::VectorImageSet(matrix([[x], [y]]), [x, y], [Dom::Interval(0, Inf), Dom::Interval(0, [1])])
```

which does not have a solution for VA and VB.

Does anyone have an idea how I can get matlab's solve() to solve for [VA VB] in terms of r, L, and X?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the *ReturnConditions* flag of the `solve` command. As in,

```
S = solve(eqns,[VA,VB],'ReturnConditions',true)
```

This will return a struct containing an array of solutions and required conditions for each.

I played around a bit with your example and hit the same roadblocks as you when making the same `assumptions`. If we start from zero assumptions, `solve` will find a set of solutions for the given equations. You could inspect the conditions for each of the given solutions and see what if any meet your original constraints?

The example given above yields results as long as VA and VB are not constrained to the Reals. Could there be a typo somewhere in your system of eqns?

Comment: I see what you're saying. Running the code while excluding the assumptions that `VB <= VA` and that `0 <= VB` still permit for a solution to be found. Some of this must be a math issue and not a coding issue. Thank you!